# Reverse lookup selectors in scss

Tags: javascript, html, sass, visual-studio-code

We have a scss structure like this:

```
.some {
  margin: 10px;
  &__other {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

When hovering `&__other` vscode helpfully tells me that I can use the class `.some__other` to use the rules described below, but it is rather difficult to do the reverse lookup.
If I am looking at the class in html like `<a href="/" class="some__other"></a>` it is impossible to use the find in project to locate the class `some__other` since it does not exist in the source files as a single string. But since vscode knows how to combine the scss rules to form the resulting selectors, is it somehow possible to perform a search for their location? Or perhaps there is an extension that allows this?

Comment: That's why it's a good idea to use the actual `.some__other` class selector directly instead of `.some { &__other }` which is almost impossible to lookup. If you need shared rules, then just do two rules `.some, .some__other { margin: 10px; }` and then `.some__other {  color: red; }`

Comment: @VLAZ I agree, but I am sadly not in control of how the styles are written. That is how the webdesigners like to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SASS compilers can be configured to generate a [source map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map).

The specifics of how you do that depend on *which* SASS compiler you are using.

When a source map is present, the developer tools in your browser's DOM Inspector will show the file name and line number of the original SASS file and not the generated CSS file.

Comment: While this does not directly answer my question, I have accepted it as it is what we ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* search with the regular expression `/.some.*&__other/gms` which will give you all matches going from a `.some` to a `&__other`. This is an *extremely* wide net you would be casting so be prepared to catch a lot of unwanted stuff.